# where to place python file when it execute with php?

Tags: php, python, html, python-3.x, machine-learning

i am finding problem in passing string from php to python code.i think my code is fine but may be in problem of path of python file.so suggest me where i have to place python file when it execute with php file.thank u so much in advance

here is my code:-

test.php

```
<?php
$s= "what is your name";
$output= shell_exec('xampp/htdocs/fbchat/public/test.py ' .$s); 
echo $output;
?>
```

test.py

```
import sys
x= sys.argv[1]
print x
```

Comment: Shouldn't the command include the python binary somewhere?

Comment: @Halcyon should.

Comment: @Kapil Sen use `which python` and add result to `'xampp/htdocs/fbchat/public/test.py '`

Comment: @kRicha i am not getting. and i m using python 3.6

Comment: @KapilSen for executing your script you need to add binary, for example on my localbox i need to use this: `$output= shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/python xampp/htdocs/fbchat/public/test.py ' .$s); `

Comment: @kRicha Shouldn't it be `/usr/bin/python` rather than `/usr/local/bin/python`?

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak on macOs it is in /usr/local/bin/, i just show an example)

Comment: @kRicha i am using window10. so i m not getting bin folder here

Comment: @KapilSen but you have `python.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your python script any where, but you need to provide its full path name(exact location).

Assuming your file is in C drive of your computer:

Try this:

```
shell_exec('python c://xampp/htdocs/fbchat/public/test.py ' . $s);
```

Comment: note: you can also use py instead python. Both mean the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shell_exec('python xampp\\htdocs\\fbchat\\public\\test.py ' . $s);
```

Comment: i tried but how should i run my python code to check output